# Run command if string match from file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm dabbling with a batch script in which I'm trying to run a command if the string read from a text file matches the local string. I managed to get the file reading part working but I can't get the `IF` condition to work and the `IF` crashes the batch script but when I remove it works.

My Batch Code,

```
@ECHO OFF

SET content=
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /f "tokens=* usebackq delims=" %%p in (file.txt) do SET content=!content!%%p

IF "%content%" == "Doit"(
ECHO boy it's working
PAUSE
) ELSE (
ECHO Not working
PAUSE
)

EndLocal
```

I'm primarily a PHP programmer not much experience with Batch scripting. Hope this is not a duplicate because I did several searches before posting this. Any way please show me how to get this done.

Comment: `cmd` is very picky about spaces. Give it a space here: `IF "%content%" == "Doit" (`. Else you compare `"Doit"` with `Doit"(` which a) never gives TRUE and b) gives you an syntax error (no command to execute)

Comment: Yes it worked thank you.

Comment: You could also `findstr /i "Doit" file.txt && ( echo boy it's working ) || (echo Not working) & pause`.  `findstr` exits 0 if a match is found, non-zero if not.  The exit code determines which conditional operator (`&&` or `||`) will be followed.

Comment: @rojo : Um, not if the file contains `D`, `o`, `i`,`t` on four separate lines...

Comment: @Magoo Ah, yeah.  I didn't examine OP's script too closely.  You're right.